# Fork a node_module in an existing git project

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have a react web app set up with NPM dependencies. My app is set up to track a remote repro where I commit its src folder and package.json. I've installed a dependency with `npm install https://github.com/some-npm-module.git --save`. My .gitignore ignores node_modules/

That is, my app's folder contains:

```
.gitignore
./node_modules/some-npm-module/
./src/
./package.json
```

Now, I need to make some modifications to some-npm-module. How can I get /node-modules/some-npm-module to track its repro while my app's source is still tracking its repro?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you make modifications to a package, you can't update it anymore without erasing everything custom.

You can however do the following :

- Fork the package on github
- make changes on your forked repo
- publish it as a separate npm module (you can restrict the scope to not make it public)
- include this new module in your project instead of the original one.

You'll then be responsible for maintaining your repo and keeping it up to date.

If you can however, I'd suggest creating a class that extends the original module, so you can keep it up to date while still being able to use your changes (until a breaking update comes along).

And if your modifications are something that would benefit the community, make a pull request to the original creator of the module and get them into the source repo!

Comment: Thanks that makes sense regarding forking. If I fork the repo on github, I'd like to clone it into my node_modules directory and work on it in there. What I'm hoping to learn is how I can have my app tracking its repo while the node_modules subdirectory tracks its own. Are git submodules the easiest way?

Comment: I'd say the easiest way would be to publish your fork as a npm under a different name. if you work into the node_modules folder then run a npm update, you'll erase all your custom code.